# background-repeat: space; not working sometimes in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a smaller background image repeat to make a pattern in the background of my site using this code in a stylesheet:

```
body
{
  background-image: url("../img/bknd3.png");
  background-position: 0px 1000px;
  background-repeat: space;
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
```

On most of my pages, this works how I want it to. There are 2 out of 6 pages where the `background-repeat: space` doesn't work. The `background-color` works on all the pages, oddly. Essentially, on the working pages, the background repeats and creates the background pattern I want, while the pages that don't work do not show the image to be repeated at all, while still having the blue background color. I am using a separate css stylesheet, so I don't think there should be any problems since the other 4 pages are referencing the same stylesheet and working fine (although I could be completely wrong).

I am fairly certain that it is the `background-repeat: space;` attribute, because when I change it to `repeat-y` or `repeat-round` they work for the 2 pages, although `repeat-x`, and `repeat` do not work properly either.

When I remove the `background-position: 0px 1000px`, what happens is that on the pages that aren't working, the `repeat: space` looks like what `repeat-x` is supposed to do.

Here are screenshots of working vs. not working:

[working page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qncWA.png)

[not working page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8eMo.png)

Comment: Check the Developer tools and choose "Inspect element" on the body element. See if any rules might get overwritten by additional CSS code you are not aware of. If the same CSS stylesheet is loaded there shouldn't be any path problems causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeat-space did not work because on those 2 pages, the only content was a

tag with basic placeholder text, so the page wasn't long enough to have the pattern repeat. The working pages had plenty of elements, so they were big enough to have the pattern repeat.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do that :

1. background-position : may top right or top center or % ..etc not putting 1000px .
2. background-repeat: should use repeat for all x, y  | or repat-x for horizontal | or repeat-y for vertical.
3. put them all in background shorthand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background